# loading a set of text files whose names are stored in an array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

So I have a set of text files that are some columns of numbers and whos names are stored in an excel file. I need to load in every file in the directory who's name matches one in the excel file. I also want to inform you all that I am a python beginner, and I'm honestly not very computer savvy (but I'm trying).

I start by loading the excel file into a dataframe and then converting it to an array. Then I was trying to loop through the array and load in any files that match it, with the name of the variable holding the data being the name of the text file (without the .txt)

```
df=pd.read_excel('names.xlsx', sheet_name="Sheet 1")
array=df.values

for i in array:
    str(array[i][0])=np.loadtxt(str(array[i][0])+'.txt')
```

when I try to run this I get:

```
str(array[i][0]) = np.loadtxt(str(array[i][0])+'.txt')
   ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

So my questions are, how can I assign that as the variable name, and because it stops before the code gets there, is it valid to load the files in the way I have?

Comment: What is `str(..) = ...` supposed to do according to you?

Comment: In another script I am running the str(..) takes the cell specified (in a loop) and names a file using it. I was hoping I could use it as a variable name, so that the files didn't load in as one big conglomerate, or be overwritten by the next iteration of the loop.

Comment: I believe this is what arrays are for, can't you just store them in elements of some new list?

Comment: What them are you referring to? The variable names or the data from the text files? If it's the variable names how do I make sure the data is tagged to the element in the list, so that when I call it I get the desired data?

Comment: I don't see a box labeled "Your Answer", I'm guessing you mean "Answer Your Question" ??

Comment: Ah - the interface is different for your own question – apologies, I don't have asked that many questions myself. If you browse other questions, you'll see the box that I referred to. Yes, this is exactly what I meant to say :) You can even mark your own answer as "Accepted" after a short waiting period (meant to discourage abuse), so others with a similar question can see this one has an answer that worked.

Answer (score 1):

I found a person to help and they led me to this:

```
df=pd.read_excel('names.xlsx', sheet_name="Sheet 1")
array=df.values

for i in array:
    x,y,z=np.loadtxt(i[0]+'.txt', dtype=float)
```

It's not exactly what I wanted to be able to do, but I can just put the other things I was going to do with the data in the loop so that it overwrites and does it again, which will work.